# View our previous comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, up-votes

Is there a way to view all our previous comments and the upvotes it has received ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not real-time (it has data through the end of April right now), but you can run a query on the [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow):

```
select * from Comments where userId = 151292 order by CreationDate
```

(replace my user id with yours)

Comment: +1. That's the only way to do it atm (query the dump): http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/438

Answer (score 2):

Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/users/297376?tab=activity#tab-top

Comment: [Sort=comments](http://stackoverflow.com/users/297376/kasturi?tab=activity&sort=comments) works better.